# Shiny updateRadioButtons

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to use upateRadioButtons in order to clear all the RadioButtons input selections. My shiny app uses several RadioButtons as input, but only the first one is cleared when using updateRadioButtons. All other RadioButtons remain at their last selection.

```
UpdateInputs <- function(data, session) {
  updateRadioButtons(session, "var1", 
                     choices = list("zero" = 0, "one" = 1, "two" = 2, "three" = 3, "four" = 4), 
                     selected = character(0), inline=T)
  updateRadioButtons(session, "var2", 
                     choices = list("zero" = 0, "one" = 1, "two" = 2, "three" = 3, "four" = 4,    
  selected = character(0), inline=T)
}
```

Comment: `selected = character(0)` looks a bit dubious.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following solution:
replacing

```
selected = character(0)
```

by

```
selected = ""
```

does the trick.